# MarkLogic 8 - Reporting and Aggregation from Large Collection

Tags: reporting, xquery, aggregation, marklogic

Say I have a collection with 100 million records/documents in it.

I want to create a series of reports that involve summing of values in certain columns and grouping by various columns.

What references for XQuery and/or MarkLogic can anyone point me to that will allow me to do this quickly?

I saw cts:avg-aggregate which looks fine. But then I need to group as well..

Also, since I am dealing with a large amount of data and it will take some time to go through it all, I am thinking about setting this up as a job that runs at night to update the report.

I thought of using corb to run through the records and then do something with the output from that. Is this the right approach with MarkLogic and reporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this guide would help:

http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/group-by-the-marklogic-way

You have several options which are discussed above:

- cts:estimate
- cts:element-value-co-occurrences
- cts:value-tuples + cts:frequency

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

The only other thing I was curious about was how to setup the architecture for running these reports..my first thought was to do some aggregation and then dump the results into a new collection for my report.

Then when I'm done with all the aggregation I could read the results from that new collection and create a report. Any thoughts on that?